# How to Export Datalayer to Access 2010?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, export, ms-access, accdb

I'm working with ArcGIS v10.1 and MS Access 2010.  Can you export a datalayer directly into Access 2010 (.accdb)? This was possible under using older versions of ArcGIS with Access 2003.

I created a DataBase Connection using ArcCatalog to reference the Access 2010 database and I can successfully import a table from Access into ArcGIS. However, when I try to export and point back to the same Access 2010 database using the same DataBase Connection, the .ODC I created is not available.

I can work around this by exporting the data into a spreadsheet and then importing the spreadsheet into Access.

Comment: What are you using Access for in this scenario?

Comment: When you say datalayer are you talking about a spatial dataset such as a point layer or a standalone non-spatial table? I think accdb databases can only support non spatial tables?

Answer (score 1):

There is a Knowledge Base Article available called **[HowTo: Connect to Microsoft Access 2007/2010 (ACCDB) files in ArcGIS](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/32976)** which says:

> The proper way of connecting to Microsoft Access databases, either the
>   MDB or ACCDB formats, is through an OLEDB connection. Though it is
>   technically possible to connect to MDB files through the Add Data
>   dialog box in ArcMap, it is not the recommended workflow. With the new
>   Microsoft Access format, accessing ACCDB files directly through the
>   Add Data dialog box is not possible.

This may be what you are after.